# HTML button to open user edit fields on

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page that displays fruitName, score, and comments (ex: "Apple", "3/5", "Juicy and sweet!").  On the bottom of the page, I want to create a "EDIT" button, which allows me to edit the score and comments by changing them into editable fields (i.e. text field for comment, drop-down menu of 1-5 scale for score), and the originally "EDIT" button now reads "SAVE CHANGES".  I am using GAE+Python+Webapp2+Jinja2

What I have so far

```
<h4>{{fruitList["fruitName"]}}</h4>
    Score:{{fruitList["score"]}}
    Comments:{{fruitName["comments"]}}
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Edit</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn">Close</button>
```

Then, I am hoping to get something like:

```
<h4>{{fruitList["fruitName"]}}</h4>
    Score:<input type=text>{{fruitList["score"]}}</input> #Preferably drop-down menu
    Comments:<input type=text>value={{fruitName["comments"]}}</input>
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Save Changes</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn">Close</button>
```

Then once the `Save Changes` button is clicked, the original "display" page will show with `Edit` and `close` buttons on the bottom.

How can I implement something like this?  I am trying solely by HTML without javascript, but unsure of feasibility. I want the page to remain stay put when "EDIT" is clicked (no redirects) and smoothly change from text display to text edit, or score.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need javascript for that.

The general idea is to initially hide the inputs and only show the text, and when the user clicks EDIT the inputs are revealed and the text is hidden. When the user clicks "Save Changes" hide the input and show the text, but copy the value to the text. When the user clicks "Close" hide the input and show the text, but copy the text to the input.

And of course, when the user clicks save changes send the changes to the server (if you need to).

**Update:**

By "copy" I mean you need to remember updating the text when the changes are saved, something like this:

```
$('#score-holder').text( $('#score-input').val() );
```

so that the text will hold the updated input

Comment: thank you.  I tried the method you mentioned and got the toggling function to work. Clicking "Edit" will allow edit mode and vice versa w/ Save Changes button.  Can you please elaborate how to "copy" the value to the text?

Comment: thanks.  I tried a variation stemming from your suggestion and now everything is working fine.